# How do I specify a custom font to be rendered in the aspx version of an SSRS/RDL report?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, fonts

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, and we are using the symbol font to display a Delta symbol in the column headers for a couple of columns on the report.  The Delta displays properly on my machine when previewing the report, but it doesn't display when I click the report in the application and view it as an aspx file -- instead, I see a D.

So far, I have:

- confirmed that the symbol font is in C:\Windows\Fonts on the report server.
- confirmed that the appropriate font is displayed if I export to PDF
- confirmed that the appropriate font is displayed if I export to Excel format
- looked around online; mostly I see advice about PDF fonts.

What else should I be checking or changing to get the font changed in the column header (but not the entire textbox; just a single character in the column header!)?
I'm testing in Firefox ESR 45.8.0, but once it is working here, I also need to confirm that it isn't a problem in Chrome.

Comment: I would try a different font like Times New Roman Δ

Comment: Okay, then let me generalize the question: How do I specify any font in the html aspx version of the report?  If I want to use Times New Roman, how do I do so?